# Nested React/Relay component not receiving props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I'm trying to pass an attribute into another component. Passing the array as `<VideoList videos={this.props.channel.video_list}></VideoList>` results in `this.props.videos` being an empty object:

```
{
  "videos": {
    "__dataID__": "client:5610611954",
    "__fragments__": {
      "2::client": "client:5610611954"
    }
  }
}
```

(GraphQL returns the correct data as confirmed by the React Chrome extension, it's just not being passed into the `VideoList`.)

**components/video_list.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Relay from 'react-relay'
import VideoItem from '../containers/video_item'    

export default class VideoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      {
        this.props.videos.edges.map(video =>
          <VideoItem key={video.id} video={video.node}/>
        )
      }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**components/channel_list.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Relay from 'react-relay'
import VideoList from './video_list'

export default class ChannelView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Column small={24}>
          <h2>{this.props.channel.title}</h2>
        </Column>

        <VideoList videos={this.props.channel.video_list}></VideoList>
      </div>


    )
  }
}
```

**containers/channel_list.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Relay from 'react-relay'
import ChannelView from '../components/channel_view'
import VideoList from './video_list'

export default Relay.createContainer(ChannelView, {
  fragments: {
    channel: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Channel {
        title
        video_list {
          ${VideoList.getFragment('videos')}
        }
      }`
  },
});
```

**containers/video_list.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Relay from 'react-relay'
import VideoList from '../components/video_list'
import VideoItem from './video_item'

export default Relay.createContainer(VideoList, {
  initialVariables: {
    count: 28
  },
  fragments: {
    videos: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Videos {
        videos(first: $count) {
          pageInfo {
            hasPreviousPage
            hasNextPage
          }
          edges {
            node {
              ${VideoItem.getFragment('video')}
            }
          }
        }
      }`
  },
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I misunderstanding how Relay works? I want to be able to set the `count` relay variable in the `VideoList` for pagination purposes. The `VideoList` object is going to be nested within multiple other components (e.g. channel, most popular, user's favorites, etc.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use the `VideoList` component directly, without the relay container wrapping it, and that's wrong.
You need to use the `VideoList` wrapped version - the one you are exporting in `./containers/video_list.js`.

Like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import Relay from 'react-relay'
import VideoList from '../containers/video_list'

export default class ChannelView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Column small={24}>
          <h2>{this.props.channel.title}</h2>
        </Column>

        <VideoList videos={this.props.channel.video_list}></VideoList>
      </div>


    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Wow, I feel dumb! I must have messed around with this for over two hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. Thank you again André!

Comment: This answer saved me after two hours of scratching my head. Thanks!